# find average shape from seed points

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is a way that I can take an array of xy coordinates and find a best fit shape from those. So for example I have a circular map of angles ranging from -90 to 90 in a disk-like shape so that the negative angles are a ring on the outside, zero in the middle and positive toward the inside. However, these are not perfectly uniform or circular, and I want to be able to fit similar values to a shape.  so far I have a bit of code that will pluck out the values close to zero:

```
slicedim = 7
x = r_[61]
y = r_[55]
for i in range (61,140):
for j in range (55,131): 
    if FA[i,j,slicedim] < 0.2:
        continue
    if ha_array[i,j,slicedim] < 10 and ha_array[i,j,slicedim] > -10:
        i_array = np.array([i])
        j_array = np.array([j])
        x = concatenate((x,i_array))
        y = concatenate((y,j_array))
```

so I have an array of the x and y values that correlate to zero. and so far I have only been able to use these values to give a best fit circle. and generate this image:

￼[image: fit circle]

but as you can see its more of an oval shape. is there something I could do to make a shape that more accurately reflects the data?